# Angular Material/CSS Centre Card contents

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to centre the text within this `angular material card` Currently it centres on horizontally, but I want it to centre vertically to

HTML:

```
<mat-card class="card-initials">
    <div>
      BD
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

CSS:

```
.card-initials{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin: 15px;
}

.card-initials div{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Heres an image of how it looks currently:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `line-height:200px`:

```
.card-initials div{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    line-height:200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/hvzeq4jr/

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot.

Comment: This makes youe line-height depend on your height, this means that it's static and not dynamic. If I were you I would rather use flexboxes

Comment: YW. Accept the answer when you can.

Comment: @BenDonnelly, setting a line height is simply ***wrong***. You don't need to know the height of the card (or hard-code it to a specific value on all devices, all browsers) to vertically center the contents. If you're using flexbox, why not `align-items`? At Alex: remember you're not only answering for OP, but for an infinity of future users. Besides, angular material has directives for it

Answer (score 3):

add `align-items:center`

```
.card-initials div{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items:center
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hvzeq4jr/1/